# Getting all values from specific field set and setting as values on another field set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dilemma I want the user to fill out a form that has `Owner` info field set when they click the next button they are presented with a `Sales` info field set that has a check box labeled `Same as Owner` So when the user clicks that check box the values in the Sales field set are automatically filled out with the info from the Owner field set. I am sure this is easy in jQuery but I am new to it and cannot determine how its done. Below I have included my code.

Sales Info:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Sales Information</legend>
        <p><label for="SalesFirstName">First Name</label> <input type="text" id="SalesFirstName" /></p>
        <p><label for="SalesLastName">Last Name</label> <input type="text" id="SalesLastName" /></p>
        <p><label for="SalesEmail">Email</label> <input type="text" id="SalesEmail" /><br /></p>
        <p><label for="SalesPhone">Phone</label> <input type="text" id="SalesPhone" /></p>
        <p><label for="SameAsOwner">Same as Owner</label><input id="SameAsOwner" name="SameAsOwner" type="checkbox" value="Yes"/></p>

        <p class="navigation"><button class="button" type="button" onclick="prevForm('SalesInfo', 'OwnerInfo');">Previous</button>                                                                                              
                        <button class="button" type="button" onclick="nextForm('SalesInfo', 'DetailedInfo' );">Next</button></p>
    </fieldset>

<script>
    $('#SameAsOwner').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            alert('checked');
        } else {
            alert('un-checked');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Owner Info:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Owner Information</legend>
        <p><label for="OwnerFirstName">First Name</label> <input type="text" id="OwnerFirstName" /></p>
        <p><label for="OwnerLastName">Last Name</label> <input type="text" id="OwnerLastName" /></p>
        <p><label for="OwnerEmail">Email</label> <input type="text" id="OwnerEmail" /><br /></p>
        <p><label for="OwnerPhone">Phone</label> <input type="text" id="OwnerPhone" /></p>


        <p class="navigation"><button class="button" type="button" onclick="prevForm('OwnerInfo', 'DealerInfo');">Previous</button>                                                                                             
                        <button class="button" type="button" onclick="nextForm('OwnerInfo', 'SalesInfo' );">Next</button></p>
    </fieldset>
```

These are all listed in separate divs the `next and prev` buttons just hide and show the divs that contain the fieldset. I have the check box `on` change function working but now I need to grab the data from only the `Owner` fields and set them as the values for the `Sales` fields.

UPDATE: 
I got the code working as intended, I am wondering if there is a way to clean it up a a bit.

```
$('#SameAsOwner').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
           var Blank = "";
           var FirstName = $( '#OwnerFirstName' ).val();
           var LastName = $( '#OwnerLastName' ).val();
           var Phone = $( '#OwnerPhone' ).val();
           var Email = $( '#OwnerEmail' ).val();
           $( "#SalesFirstName" ).val( FirstName );
           $( "#SalesLastName" ).val( LastName );
           $( "#SalesEmail" ).val( Email );
           $( "#SalesPhone" ).val( Phone );
        } else {
           $( "#SalesFirstName" ).val( Blank );
           $( "#SalesLastName" ).val( Blank );
           $( "#SalesEmail" ).val( Blank );
           $( "#SalesPhone" ).val( Blank );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean it up in the sense of not using variables, just `$( "#SalesFirstName" ).val( $( '#OwnerFirstName' ).val() );`

Another method is to define an array/object of fields that match up and then just loop through them.

Or if you want the form fields themselves to dictate which field they fill, you can use `data-` attributes and read that in jquery.